# How to avoid pytest mocked data conflicting between tests

Tags: python, pytest, pytest-mock

I have two commands (django management commands) which load data from an API, then do something based on the data they collect. So certain function names are the same for consistency, like `get_api_data` to gather data and `get_specific_event` to get an event from the data.

In the test module for each command I have a function that returns a dictionary to represent the data from the API which the command expects. For example;

```
#test_command_one.py

from core.management.commands.command_one import Command as CommandOne

def get_data(current_event=None, next_event=1):
    return {
        "current": current_event,
        "next": next_event,
        "data": [
            {
                "id": i,
                "time": time,
            }
            for i, time in enumerate(
                [
                    "2023-08-11 17:30:00+00:00",
                    "2023-08-18 17:15:00+00:00",
                    "2023-08-25 17:30:00+00:00",
                    "2023-09-01 17:30:00+00:00",
                    "2023-09-16 10:00:00+00:00",
                ],
                start=1,
            )
        ],
    }


@pytest.mark.django_db
class TestCommandOne:

    def test_get_current_event(self, mocker):
        cmd = CommandOne()
        m_events = mocker.patch.object(cmd, "get_api_data")

        m_events.return_value = get_data(next_event=1)
        assert cmd.get_current_event() is None
```

```
#test_command_two.py

from project.management.commands.command_two import Command

def get_events():
    return {
        "data": [
            {
                "id": i,
                "time": time,
                "time2": time,
                "time3": time,
            }
            for i, time in enumerate(
                [
                    "2023-08-11 17:30:00+00:00",
                    "2023-08-18 17:15:00+00:00",
                    "2023-08-25 17:30:00+00:00",
                    "2023-09-01 17:30:00+00:00",
                    "2023-09-16 10:00:00+00:00",
                ],
                start=1,
            )
        ],
    }


def test_valid_output(mocker):
    mocker.patch.object(
        Command, "get_api_data", return_value=get_events()
    )
    out2 = StringIO()
    call_command("command_two", stdout=out2)
    assert out2.getvalue() == "test output"
```

Running the tests in isolation they pass. But when running the whole test suite, I'm seeing;

```
FAILED project/tests/test_command_two.py::test_valid_output - KeyError: 'time2'
```

So the data being used by the second test is still the return value of `m_events = mocker.patch.object(cmd, "get_api_data")` in the first test. But switching the order in which the tests run, still fails on the same issue, so it's not like it loads the mock from one test and then still uses that on the second test.

How do I either clear these mocks at the beginning of a test, or ensure that the new mock is used?

I'd expect that each time you define `mocker.patch.object(cmd, "get_api_data")` for a test, it's specified return value is the one used for the context of that test.

Comment: In your second test, you patch the Command object but never use it. What does `call_command` do? The mocker fixture restores all patched objects after each test. I suspect that the code you are testing retains some global state.

Comment: @danzel Ah yes good catch. That test captures the output of the command in order to assert what it is. So `call_command` is a django utility to call commands from code. Things you'd otherwise execute from the command line.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/django-admin/#running-management-commands-from-your-code

Answer (score 0):

The error in the code 1 is that the assertion `assert cmd.get_current_event() is None` is failing. This means that the value returned by `cmd.get_current_event()` is not `None`.

To debug the issue, you can print the value returned by `cmd.get_current_event()` and check what it actually is. This will help you understand why the assertion is failing and fix the issue.

Comment: This may be usefull with the first code

Comment: To resolve the second you sould do the same

Comment: The error in the second code is that the assertion `assert out2.getvalue() == "test output"` is failing. This means that the value returned by `out2.getvalue()` is not equal to the string "test output".

To debug the issue, you can print the value returned by `out2.getvalue()` and check what it actually is. This will help you understand why the assertion is failing and fix the issue.

Comment: Adding `print(f"TEST: {cmd.get_next_event()}\n\n")` into that test outputs `None` so that assert must be passing. Changing the assert to 1, I see `test_get_next_event - assert None is 1` so I'm happy that it's working there.